# Radio Button CakePHP 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 2.0 I can actually add 'before', 'after' and 'separator' attributes to the radio button. The attributes will create a div element between my radio options. It seems like these options have been removed from CakePHP 3.0. How can I do that in CakePHP 3.0?

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="square-screening single-row screen-radio">
      <?php echo $this->Form->input('q1',array(
          'legend'=> false,
          'type'=>'radio',
          'options'=> $options,
          'required'=>'required',
          'before' => '<div class="radio-inline screen-center screen-radio">',
          'separator' => '</div><div class="radio-inline screen-center screen-radio">',
          'after' => '</div>',
      )); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use **FormHelper Templates**. From migration guide:

> The separator, between, and legend options have been removed from radio(). You can use templates to change the wrapping HTML now.
>
> The div, before, after, between and errorMessage options have been removed from input().

so in your case use this

```
echo $this->Form->input('q1', [
    'templates' => [
        'radioWrapper' => '<div class="radio-inline screen-center screen-radio">{{label}}</div>'
    ],
    'type' => 'radio',
    'options' => $options,
    'required' => 'required',
    'label' => false
]);
```

See also:

- **[Customizing the Templates FormHelper Uses](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses)**
- **[FormHelper Templates - default values](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/source-class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#78-123)**

Answer (score 1):

It so very easy.

You can use form helper.

```
Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper::radio(string $fieldName, array $options, array $attributes)
```

Using

```
echo $this->Form->radio(
    'favorite_color',
    [
        ['value' => 'r', 'text' => 'Red', 'style' => 'color:red;'],
        ['value' => 'u', 'text' => 'Blue', 'style' => 'color:blue;'],
        ['value' => 'g', 'text' => 'Green', 'style' => 'color:green;'],
    ]
);
```

[Docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-radio-buttons)

Comment: Hi Soft Kitty, I've read the Docs. That is when you want to add custom attributes to the input element. What my doubt is how do I add a opening '<div class="radio-inline screen-center screen-radio">' and closing '</div>' between the radio option, and not an attribute in the radio option. Thanks.

Comment: Hi DANLEE. You can see this chapter docs. 
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses

It's using templates, that can to merge with your html input.